# I am placing an "Image Pixel Tag" on my website using custom Image tag. I want the tag to fire on top of the page

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have placed a custom Image Tag on my website using the google tag manager. Currently, it is firing at the bottom section of the page. But I want that to fire on top of the page.

The Image Pixel is given in the Custom Image Tag. And the trigger condition is given for specific pages.

Is there any way where I can make it fire on the top of the page?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have this kind of control in GTM. The best you can do is check that GTM is implemented on the head of the site and put a trigger on gtm.js (page view) with fire priority.

Hope it helps!